# longest common prefix gives the 0 index only in strings

Tags: python

I'm using this function to get the longest common prefix in two strings, I work on python 2.7.13 version but the function gives me the 0 index only.

```
def longestcommonPrefix(s1, s2):
i = 0
while i < len(s1) and i < len(s2) and s1[i] == s2[i]:
    i += 1
    return s1[:i]
longestcommonPrefix("ACCATGT", "ACCAGAC")
```

Comment: Hi Maloki. Welcome to stack exchange. It seems when you pasted your code it had some formatting errors. Would you be able to edit it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other solution resolves the problem with your syntax / indentation. Also note this functionality already exists in the standard library:

```
from os.path import commonprefix

res = commonprefix(["ACCATGT", "ACCAGAC"])  # 'ACCA'
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through the code using Python 2.7.13. Probably you just need to indent the code correctly. See a working example below:

```
def longestcommonPrefix(s1, s2):
    i = 0
    while i < len(s1) and i < len(s2) and s1[i] == s2[i]:
        i += 1
    return s1[:i]

test = longestcommonPrefix("ACCATGT", "ACCAGAC")
```

Comment: thank you very much it was an indentation error, I fixed it .